# AngularJS: How to initialize data through $http before executing other part of the code?

Tags: angularjs

I have below code

```
$scope.init = function (){        
        console.log($scope.languageFilePath);
        $http.get($scope.languageFilePath) //languageFilePath contain url
       .then(function(res){
            console.log('scueese');          
            $scope.translate = res.data;          
            console.log($scope.translate.SERVICE);
            // $scope.eqipment = $scope.translate['COLOR'];
            //console.log("Data String "+equip);
            //$scope.eqipment="ghsh"
        });    
    };
    $scope.init();
```

Now what is my issue this method calling properly but before initializing  `$scope.translate` its executing other part of code.

What changes i have to do in the code so first its initialize `$scope.translate` then only it call some other methods of file .

Note:- $http.get() method calling when this method invoked after that other methods are executing and code inside `then` executing after those method called.

Comment: I have 3 questions . This init is for only a part of your app or for only this scope  ? are you sure thre is no other function call before ? what is executed before ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO the above code executing but `then` condition calling after other function called .

Comment: you mean that a code that is under `$scope.init()` is invoked before `$scope.translate`, correct?

Comment: that's the nature of js..

Comment: @AvinashRaj then how to initialize  `$scope.translate` before calling other function because this data used by other function

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO Edited my question

Comment: call `$scope.init();` inside then function (just after to translate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is to execute the code after $scope.init() invocation, you could try to use the http.get promise, like this:

```
    $scope.init = function (){        
        console.log($scope.languageFilePath);
        return $http.get($scope.languageFilePath) //languageFilePath contain url
          .then(function(res){
            console.log('scueese');          
            $scope.translate = res.data;          
            console.log($scope.translate.SERVICE);
        });    
    };
    $scope.init().then(function(){
      //this code will be executed after the http get...
});
```

**EDIT 1**

after receiving some more code from OP, you should modify your .js file as shown here: http://pastebin.com/mFUWSU0N

this way, ALL the code below init() will be executed after the $http.get completion.

Comment: Do you mean i have to give two `then` ?

Comment: Give to who? This way, you are "chaining" the promise of the $http.get ($http uses promises to perform http requests). More simply, with the above code you will execute code after your http.get

Comment: i am getting this error angular.js:12330 `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Please provide a plunker of your issue. as you can see from here, there's nothing wrong on promise chain: http://plnkr.co/edit/A9fq3IAHtC45L7KY2J0k?p=info so maybe the problem it's related to your code.

Comment: I dont know how you run my code in plnkr because for me data is loading from rest url. Do you want to check the full file then i can add it there.

Comment: It's ok for me. try to upload to some service (like pastebin) but i can't guarantee i will able to find a solution.

Comment: here you can check js file http://plnkr.co/edit/5sHexeXlrnQmaMyVKIEz?p=info

Comment: at row 21 you should add 'return' before the $http.get call, as shown in my answer.
(see updated plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/y6H6aJO08QN1hcTlh2mJ?p=info)

Comment: will update you morning the guy which have all code left the office .

Comment: Please bear in mind that even with that return statement, your code will not magically work: your code posted in the plunker does nothing inside the $scope.init().then function. See my edited answer for updated (hopefully)solution.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should out the wanted function in your init:

```
$scope.init = function (){        
        console.log($scope.languageFilePath);
        return $http.get($scope.languageFilePath) //languageFilePath contain url
          .then(function(res){
            console.log('scueese');          
            $scope.translate = res.data;          
            console.log($scope.translate.SERVICE);
            myFunc();
            myFunc2();
        });    
    };
```

Comment: i cannt change code like this some of the function related to ui-grid which i don't have direct control

Comment: so the ui-grid is initialized before your init

Comment: Yes ui-grid initialized before data initialize in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you also could do is make it a dependency of your controller.
        Lets say for instance you are using the routeprovider to navigate to your page you could then do this:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider.when('../../goto/yourpage', {
        templateUrl: '/yourpage.html', 
        controller: 'myController',
        resolve: {
            initializeFunction: function($http) {
                // do some logic you want executed before anything else
                 return $http.get("blablabla").$promise;
              });    
            }
        }
    });   
}]);
```

then in your controller that is active on yourpage.html you can do:

```
myApp.controller('myController',function ($scope,initializeFunction) {
    $scope.possibleReturnFromTheFunction = initializeFunction; 
});
```